# Use replace function inside Meteor.js Spacebars

Tags: javascript, meteor, replace

I am using `Meteor.js` and am working with their [Spacebars Template system](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md). The system won't allow me to use JavaScript's `replace` function. What am I doing wrong here?

```
{{#each this.PDFs}}
    <h5>{{this.replace(/\+(.*)$/,'')}}</h5><li class="pdf-document"><a href="{{file this}}" target="{{this}}" class="icon-document"></a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: You can't execute arbitrary js expressions in spacebars - you'll need to add a [helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_helpers).

Comment: like david says just use a helper like `replacePdf:function(str){ return str.replace(/\+(.*)$/,'')}` and then use it like `{{replacePdf this}}`